# Using custom paths with will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I've got the following in routes.rb:

```
# Legacy Search URL
get "/used-guitars/search", to: 'guitars#index', as: 'legacy_search'
```

And I'm trying to get the `will_paginate` gem to use my legacy_search urls when paginating the index action for the guitars controller:

```
= will_paginate @guitars
```

Results in pagination links with href's like so:

```
/guitars?page=2
```

When what I want is:

```
/used-guitars/search?page=2
```

I've had a read through the code and there is no option to provide a path parameter.

What to do? I will abandon will_paginate if I can't get this working, I'll just write my own code if I have to because this is a showstopper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by moving my legacy route above the other one like so:

```
get "/used-guitars/search", to: 'guitars#index', as: 'legacy_search'
resources :guitars
```

Easy when you know how.